# Получение списка документов по которым не было оплаты.

Tags: 1с

Всем доброго времени суток!
Суть задачи:

- есть запрос который возвращает задолженность по контрагенту, на определённую дату, по договору с определённой организацией. (возвращает просто число)
  `"ВЫБРАТЬ РАЗРЕШЕННЫЕ
                          ВзаиморасчетыСКонтрагентамиОстатки.Контрагент КАК Контрагент,
                          ВзаиморасчетыСКонтрагентамиОстатки.СуммаВзаиморасчетовОстаток КАК СуммаВзаиморасчетов
                      ИЗ
                          РегистрНакопления.ВзаиморасчетыСКонтрагентами.Остатки(
                                  &ДатаКон,
                                  Контрагент = &Контрагент
                                      И Организация = &Организация) КАК ВзаиморасчетыСКонтрагентамиОстатки
                      УПОРЯДОЧИТЬ ПО
                          Контрагент
                      ИТОГИ
                          СУММА(СуммаВзаиморасчетов)
                      ПО
                          ОБЩИЕ
                      {ИТОГИ ПО
                          Контрагент.*}
                      АВТОУПОРЯДОЧИВАНИЕ"`

Вопрос: можно ли как то этот запрос переделать так что бы он возвращал список документов "Реализация товаров и услуг"(определённого контрагента по договору с определённой организацией) по которым не было оплаты?  И если можно, то как это сделать, что изменить?.....
Буду благодарен за любую помощь.
P.S. сам я в 1С вообще не шарю, пытаюсь писать на C#.... Так что помидорами просьба не бросаться.

Comment: Можно, нужно сделать запрос по  движениям по регистру взаиморвсчетов

Comment: Mikhail Chibel а рабочей ссылочкой или примером запроса, вы поделится можете?

Comment: К сожалению нет,  9 лет как с 1с завязал.

Comment: Какая конфигурация у вас?

Comment: Aleksandr K. вы имеете в виду типовая или нет? Если да, то типовая.

Answer (score 0):

Прямо как в "твоем вопросе" надо и писать ! Это же русский - великий и могучий )

```
ВЫБРАТЬ *
ИЗ Документ."Реализация товаров и услуг" КАК РТУ
ГДЕ РТУ.контрагент = &контрагент И
РТУ.организация = &организация И
<Не было Оплаты признак>
```

(определённого контрагента по договору с определённой организацией) по которым не было оплаты?

Comment: Спасибо. А сюда <Не было Оплаты признак> вы не знаете что подставлять?

Answer (score 0):

Для ваших целей нужно использовать регистр `ВзаиморасчетыСКонтрагентамиПоДокументамРасчетов`. Только в этот регистр делают движения документы по договорам, у которых установлен признак `Вести по документам расчетов`. Если учет по документам расчетов не ведется, то и остатки по конкретным реализациям (документам расчетов) нигде не хранятся. Их можно попытаться рассчитать по всем движениям, гася задолженности по FIFO например. Но это дело неблагодарное, и при большом документообороте может просто не хватить аппаратных ресурсов.

Comment: Не уверен что правильно вас понял.... По этому вкратце обрисую ситуацию. Банк в 1С-ке сводится вручную, бухгалтерами. т. е. Бухгалтера сами закрывают оплату по документам. Мне нужно получить те документы, по которым не было оплаты, на определённую дату.

Comment: Какая конфигурация используется?

Comment: Михаил Дуров "Управление торговым предприятием для Украины", редакция 1.2. 
Разработка конфигурации: "ABBYY Ukraine", 2007-2016 (1.2.38.1) (http://1c.ua/v8/RegionalSolutions_UA_UTP.php)
Copyright © ООО "1C", 2007-2016
(http://www.1c.ru)